# Vim says 'missing :endif', but I'm sure its there

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Consider the following vim code.

```
function! s:foo()
    if s:bar()
        let a = 1
    endif
endfunction

function! s:bar()
python << EOF
vim.command('echoerr "blabla"')
EOF
endfunction

command! Foo call s:foo()
map <F7> :Foo<CR>
```

Open a vim session and press F7.
Vim wil then throw an error saying `E171: Missing :endif`.
How is this possible and how can I correctly send an error message inside the python part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside a function, `:echoerr` works like `:throw` and raises an exception. Normal control flow is interrupted and Vim complains it didn't see the `:endif`. `:echoerr` is practically useless inside a function, also because an entire multi-line stacktrace is shown.

I would solve this by just setting `v:errmsg` (or any other custom variable or flag), and then check for and report the error directly at the conclusion of your function:

```
function! s:foo()
    let v:errmsg = ''
    if s:bar()
        let a = 1
    endif
endfunction

function! s:bar()
python << EOF
vim.command('let v:errmsg = "blabla"')
EOF
endfunction

command! Foo call s:foo() | if ! empty(v:errmsg) | echoerr v:errmsg | endif
map <F7> :Foo<CR>
```

Comment: On a side note: `!empty(string)` is very inefficient, since it has to convert `string` to a list first.  Consider using `len(string)` instead, or just `string !=# ''`.  It's a widespread mistake...

Comment: Sorry, `len(string)` should be `strlen(string)`.

Comment: @lcd047: Have you actually measured it? I don't see any remarkable difference, and I don't think there will be an explicit conversion to a List. Oh, and `len()` and `strlen()` are identical for Strings.

Comment: I looked at the sources; Vim doesn't try to optimise anything, even inroads like this.  This approach makes sense from a developer's point of view.  Not so much from a user's point of view.  `len()`, just like `empty()`, is a list function.  The speed difference doesn't matter when you call it once; it might start to add up when you call it from a sort function.  But even if it's a pointless optimisation, it's still a small detail in understanding the language (at least it is to me). _shrug_

Comment: @lcd047 `empty()` has understood how to efficiently check for an empty string since it was [first implemented](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/e49b69a#diff-de9ab8906fef668ed8042046e0a1eb02R5526) in 2005.

Answer (score 2):

`if s:bar()` expects `s:bar()` to return a value, but `s:bar()` doesn't.  Hence the "missing :endif".

On a side note, you also didn't `import vim` for the Python code (not sure that's still required though).

**Update:** `echoerr` also raises a `vim.error`.  Try this instead:

```viml
function! s:bar()
    python <<EOF
import vim

vim.command('normal \<Esc>')
vim.command('echohl ErrorMsg')
vim.command('echomsg "blabla"')
vim.command('echohl None')
EOF
    return 1
endfunction
```